Why does the C Standard prohibit a partial preprocessing token at the end of a source file?
I'm reading ISO C draft standard n3096 and notice the following bold statement (§ 5.1.1.2 p1):


The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. Each comment is replaced by one character. New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.


This statement also appears in C90, and presumably every standard in between.
My question is: why does the Standard explicitly prohibit a source file from ending in a partial preprocessing token? Is this statement not made redundant by other declarations of undefined behavior?

First, I will provide my (mis)understanding.
As a working definition, because the C Standard does not mention "partial preprocessing token" in any other place, I defer to this informative footnote in the C++ Standard (n4928, § 5.2 [lex.phases]):

10) A partial preprocessing token would arise from a source file ending in the first portion of a multi-character token that requires a terminating sequence of characters, such as a header-name that is missing the closing " or >. ...

...where header-name is a kind of preprocessing-token, defined (§ 6.4 p1)

preprocessing-token:

header-name
identifier
pp-number
character-constant
string-literal
punctuator
each universal-character-name that cannot be one of the above
each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above


From this, I believe the preprocessing tokens that can be "partial" include at least header-name, character-constant, string-literal, and hexadecimal-floating-constant (a kind of pp-number that is terminated by a binary-exponent-part).
Regarding the statement prohibiting partial preprocessing tokens at the end of a source file: I assume it is not redundant, and it prohibits some case not already prohibited elsewhere. Assuming a source file ending in a partial preprocessing token is non-empty, and given that a non-empty source file is already required to end in a new-line character not part of a line splice (§ 5.1.1.2 p1), I believe the aforementioned statement describes the case where the source file ends in a new-line not part of a line splice, and also ends in a partial preprocessing token; so the partial preprocessing token contains a new-line after translation phase 2.
But, preprocessing tokens do not contain new-lines after TP 2. (/* comments can though, which is why the prohibition of partial comments makes sense to me.)
(If it is relevant, I am also confused about the concept of a partial preprocessing token in the first place... It is apparently not a preprocessing token, but I thought there are no invalid preprocessing tokens because of the fallback in the preprocessing-token rule, "each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above.")

Sorry for the long question...
Many thanks,

Checked the standard and emm it's quite more complex than I thought. I grabbed some standard definitions while doing that research. I think the op should have read these but maybe it helps other people seeing this post like me: https://pastebin.com/gKZuKCpC

I suspect it's largely pragmatic. Try to imagine what a fully standards-compliant preprocessor and tokenizer would have to do if this rule wasn't there, It permits a preprocesser implementation that is very easy to reason about. Otherwise, the preprocessor could paste the contents of a file due to an #include and suddenly all contents afterwards possibly need to be re-tokenized and preprocessesed (twice? before/after that one #include was expanded?), and you would not legally be able to tokenize header files independently.

@Limina102 Thank you for the fast reply! I have added a couple of your excerpts to the post.

Your question seems to be almost exactly the same to the defect report 324 https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_324.htm , which asks:

Assuming there is a non-empty source file legally ending with a new-line character, what are examples of such partial preprocessing tokens that could end the file? And, generally, what the partial preprocessing tokens are?



As a working definition, because the C Standard does not mention "partial preprocessing token" in

From DR324:

"Partial preprocessing token" is not itself a technical term; it is merely the English Language word "partial" modifying the technical term "preprocessing token". A preprocessing token is defined by the grammar non-terminal preprocessing-token in Subclause 6.4. A partial preprocessing token is therefore just part of a preprocessing token that is not the entire preprocessing token.



why does the Standard explicitly prohibit a source file from ending in a partial preprocessing token? Is this statement not made redundant by other declarations of undefined behavior?

From DR324:

The statement that "source files shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment" has two implications. First, a preprocessing token may not begin in one file and end in another file. Second, the last preprocessing token in a source file must be well-formed and complete. For example, the last token may not be a string literal missing the close quote.


Overall, I think the issue is about:
// string.h
"am I a string

// main.c
#include <string.h>\
literal?"


I was not aware of a related defect report, thank you for linking it! The intention being that preprocessing tokens cannot span multiple files as a result of #include makes a lot of sense to me.

A third implication of this statement is that it makes it a constraint violation for the file to end in a partial preprocessing token, and so a diagnostic must be issued when it is encountered, even if the actual behavior is undefined.

@NateEldredge Could you elaborate why a constraint is implied?

@nore: I mean, it clearly is a constraint as defined by 3.8, is it not?

@NateEldredge I'm not an expert, but I believe constraints must be introduced explicitly with the word "constraint." For example, "If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints" (§ 5.1.2.2.1 p2). Or, constraints can be introduced under a subheading titled "Constraints." The statement in question does not have this context, so "shall not" instead describes UB (§ 4 p2). We also see in Annex J.2 that the statement is second in the list of UB. (Though Annex J is informative.)

Tokens are very difficult to parse if EOF is interspersed inside... just imagine something like
#define PRIVATE(_var) _var ##   <here is EOF>

and next file starts with a new line.  How can this be interpreted.

Worse, imagine this:
/* This is the start of a comment  
<EOF>

should the file including this one start in comment mode?

Or even
char array_of_chars[] = "This is the start of a string literal \
<EOF>

should the continuation file start with
and this is the continuation of the string literal";

a scanner that should remain in some state while scanning half of a token is by far more difficult to parse, and requires very difficult buffering management.  Normally, end of input is something not well defined in the language, and is difficult to handle transparently in a scanner in the middle of a token.
EOF has different treatement when handled in the end of an include file, but is the same symbol when detected at end of input.  It is a pseudosymbol at the end of the compilation unit that must end to make parsing to work.
Had I been selected to define end of file restrictions I should prohibit to end a file also between a closing brace that must be followed by a semicolon, because there's a common error when you define a struct in a header file and forget to end the structure definition in a semicolon.  The syntax error is normally marked in the next file (in the including file) two or three tokens later, because syntax is correct and you have defined a struct without ending the declaration with a semicolon, the thing is interpreted as a type and the compiler expects an object identifier, not a type which is what normally follows.

I disagree with the first assertion: the tokenizer itself never even need see the EOF between files; this is a very easy thing to ignore. I do agree that coding is generally made simpler if it is not a possibility, though. All your other points are spot-on, IMHO — a file is a conceptual boundary intended to encapsulate other bounding things, like comments and strings. Hence, mixing the two is a moral failure. (IOW, the wording could be improved, methinks)

the tokenizer is what sees the EOF and switches files, and not only that.... it must signal the parser that input has ended to properly end the main symbol in the context free grammar.  You can dissagree, but it is the tokenizer what has to switch input from the included file to the (probably already buffered) input in the includer file, more if buffering is being done.  Have you ever implemented an include files feature in a parser?  At least flex derived tokenizers allow you to do this way.

I’ve written more than a few tokenizer/parsers, some with include mechanisms of varying design. My point is that EOF is not itself an issue. It is the syntax requirements of the language that is the issue. In C, EOF represents a hard boundary. This is not a technical limitation of the file structure nor of the software picking things apart.

Given your first example (and assuming EOF is acceptable), if the next file were to start with a newline that would simply be a syntax error, not a problem introduced by an EOF, or buffering, or any other kind of file management. (The tokenizer itself should not be directly reading the file, and stacking an input file is not a difficult software design problem.) The actual reason has to do with how humans perceive files.

In other words, leading with “Tokens are very difficult to parse if EOF is interspersed inside” is not necessarily true, and it colors your answer to justify that assertion. It would be more correct to say that EOF in the middle of a production is problematic because it makes it too easy for us humans to break syntax. I like the examples you give showing exactly how that becomes an issue.

Though I can also accept that, historically, excessively simplistic tokenizers of the time may have had something to do with it. (Sorry for the wall of text.)
